# Adding time series line in front of barplot

Tags: r, line, bar-chart

I would like to add a line to a barplot. However, when I use the following code, the resulting line does not fit into the plot - it is too short, even though the data series of the line has the same length as the barplot data series.

Here a reproducible example:

```
pos <- c(4,5,5,6,4,6,4,5.5,6,8,7)
neg <- c(-8,-7,-7,-7,-6,-7,-5,-6,-6.5,-9,-7)
net <- pos+neg

plot.par <- par(mfrow=c(1,1))
par(mar=c(4,4.5,2,1))
plot(pos, type="n", main="", cex.main=1.1, xlab="", 
     ylab="", cex.lab=1.3, yaxt= "n", xaxt="n", ylim=c(-10, 10))
abline(h=c(-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10),col = grey(0.6), lty=3)
abline(v=c(1,4,7), 
       col = grey(0.6), lty=3)
par(new=T)
barplot(pos, main="", cex.main=1.1, xlab="", col="darkolivegreen", border="darkolivegreen",
        ylab="", cex.lab=1.1, yaxt= "n", xaxt="n", ylim=c(-10, 10))
par(new=T)
barplot(neg, main="", cex.main=1.1, xlab="", col="darkgoldenrod3",border="darkgoldenrod3",
        ylab="", cex.lab=1.1, yaxt= "n", xaxt="n", ylim=c(-10, 10))
par(new=T)
lines(net, col="firebrick4", lwd = 4)
```

Using this code, the plot looks the following way:
[image]

Comment: Can you add some reproducible data using `dput()` for instance.

Comment: @Jimbou: I added some data, hope that helps...

Comment: @Lila can you show the output of `dput(prodlong.plot)` and so on?

Comment: @Lila Using your sample data (actually, the data for yellow == data for green) I have no problems to plot the line above and until the end of the bars.

Comment: @Jimbou: do you use the same commands and the same order of commands as I do in the code?

Comment: please check the values in `h` when using this function: `h <- barplot(a, ylim=c(-5000,5000))`. This are the true x values of the middle of the bars. So you have to use this: `h <- barplot(a, ylim=c(-5000,5000)); barplot(-a,ylim=c(-5000,5000),add=T);lines(x = h[,1],b, lwd=2)`

Comment: @Jimbou: hmm it does not work. I changed it to a more reproducible example. Maybe you can help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
# creating the barplots 
h <- barplot(pos, ylim=c(-10,10), col="darkolivegreen", border="darkolivegreen", yaxt="n")
barplot(neg, add=T, col="darkgoldenrod3",border="darkgoldenrod3",yaxt="n")

# adding the horizontal ablines
abline(h=c(-10,-8,-6,-4,-2,0,2,4,6,8,10),col = grey(0.6), lty=3)
abline(v=h[c(1,4,7)], col = grey(0.6), lty=3)

# plot the barplots again to overplot the ablines
barplot(pos, ylim=c(-10,10), col="darkolivegreen", border="darkolivegreen",add=T)
barplot(neg, add=T, col="darkgoldenrod3",border="darkgoldenrod3", yaxt="n")

# add the line using x values stored in h...the true positions of the middle of each bar
lines(x=h,y=net, col="firebrick4", lwd = 4)

# the box around the plot
box()
```

[image]

As an alternative you can use ggplot2 as well. The data preparation is done using `dplyr`and `tidyr`. All packages are included in the super package `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- cbind.data.frame(id=seq_along(pos), pos, neg)
d %>% mutate(net=pos+neg) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -id, -net) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=id, y=value, fill=key)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  geom_line(aes(x=id, y=net), size=3) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1,4,7))+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor.x=element_blank())+
  ylim(-10,10)
```

[image]